# Check click outside of View

Tags: android, layout

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Style Theme.Transparent -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I set a onclicklistener to parent and child view:

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
videoView.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
```

I get only click events for video view. 
What I want is to know if the user clicks into the video view or outside (parent) and do different actions. How do I get this behavior?

Thanks
Tata

Comment: Please show your code of myOnlyhandler.

Comment: you sill get click event of videoView even if you click outside of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A while ago I've implemented an `Activity` base class that offers such functionality. You simply register a custom `OnTouchOutsideViewListener` that gets notified once the user touches outside your view after having installed a listener. Simply call `setOnTouchOutsideViewListener` on your activity instance.

You can paste this code into your existing activity class or create a base activity class that you can reuse throughout your project.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {

private View mTouchOutsideView;

private OnTouchOutsideViewListener mOnTouchOutsideViewListener;

/**
 * Sets a listener that is being notified when the user has tapped outside a given view. To remove the listener,
 * call {@link #removeOnTouchOutsideViewListener()}.
 * <p/>
 * This is useful in scenarios where a view is in edit mode and when the user taps outside the edit mode shall be
 * stopped.
 *
 * @param view
 * @param onTouchOutsideViewListener
 */
public void setOnTouchOutsideViewListener(View view, OnTouchOutsideViewListener onTouchOutsideViewListener) {
    mTouchOutsideView = view;
    mOnTouchOutsideViewListener = onTouchOutsideViewListener;
}

public OnTouchOutsideViewListener getOnTouchOutsideViewListener() {
    return mOnTouchOutsideViewListener;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Notify touch outside listener if user tapped outside a given view
        if (mOnTouchOutsideViewListener != null && mTouchOutsideView != null
            && mTouchOutsideView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            mTouchOutsideView.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);
            if (!viewRect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
                mOnTouchOutsideViewListener.onTouchOutside(mTouchOutsideView, ev);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event has occurred outside a formerly specified
 * view. See {@link #setOnTouchOutsideViewListener(View, OnTouchOutsideViewListener).}
 */
public interface OnTouchOutsideViewListener {

    /**
     * Called when a touch event has occurred outside a given view.
     *
     * @param view  The view that has not been touched.
     * @param event The MotionEvent object containing full information about the event.
     */
    public void onTouchOutside(View view, MotionEvent event);
}    

}
```

Comment: Good answer overall. You may want dispatchTouchEvent() to return true if the touch was outside of the view, so that the touch event is consumed. Also, it is more common to trigger on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

Comment: This answer is just PERFECT!

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks man.